# Multiple foreign key in 1 to n relation

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

```
public class Folder
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public DateTime FileName { get; set; }

    public virtual Folder Folder { get; set; }
}
```

**Chanllange**  to decorate methods of File class so that:

```
 new File() {Folder = folder, FileName= "bla-bla"};
```

automatically set FolderName property of the File object by value of folder.Name

Is it possible to do over attributes?

**Level of complecity 2**

```
public class Folder
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string PC { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string PC { get; set; }
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public DateTime FileName { get; set; }

    public virtual Folder Folder { get; set; }
}
```

the same question
   how to train the model to set foreign keys automaticallyy after the instruction

```
new File() {Folder=folder, FileName='bla-bla'}
```

**update** 
In very short how to write the following down over the attributes

```
HasRequired(a => a.Folder).WithMany(b => b.Files).HasForeignKey(c => new { c.Pc, c.FolderName});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `Folder` property from auto-implemented to property with backing field, and set `FolderName` in its setter. Also add foreign key attribute to this property:

```
public class File
{
    private Folder _folder;

    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public DateTime FileName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FolderName")]
    public virtual Folder Folder
    {
        get { return _folder; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();

            _folder = value;
            FolderName = _folder.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: implementation of the propery smells not good. ;) decoration [ForeignKey("FolderName")] should be enough and work... need to try. but it still not a thing I wanted to ask. see an update soon

Comment: @YaugenVlasau unfortunately `ForeignKey` will not change `FolderName` value when you assign `Folder` to `File`. Foreign keys updated only when you save entity

Comment: it is possible when it goes in EntityTypeConfiguration. for example HasRequired(a => a.Folder).WithOptional(p => p.File). I just wanted to ask can I do the same over the attribute? :)

Comment: @YaugenVlasau I think you should have `HasMany(f => f.Files).WithRequired(f => f.Folder).HasForeignKey(f => f.FolderName)`. Thats what you have with attributes. But again, you need to set FolderName manually in setter.

Comment: as for: .HasForeignKey(f => f.FolderName) - thats right. +1 for contribution but still have a gut feeling that should work without a setter. will post anothe update to the question